# How to validate in JS if an HTML5 input pattern has been matched?

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="number_field" pattern="[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+" />
```

I can target custom css if the pattern is not matched using the `:invalid` selector.

I want to disable a submit button that makes an XHR if all the validation isn't met.

```
<button class="AdamBrown" onclick="saveAdamBrown(12)">Save</button>
```

***How can I assess whether the pattern is met in Javascript?***

Comment: Simply add required to `input` tag

Comment: You'd be better off putting the inputs in an actual `form` and using the form's `submit` event to know that validation passed.

Answer (score 6):

```
var input = document.getElementById("number_field")
input.checkValidity()
```

[checkValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity) will simply return true or false. If you want to know why it fails validation, you can explore the `input.validity` object.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the HTML5 constraint validation API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation
). You can check if you input pattern check is valid by checking the value of `validity.patternMismatch` of that element. Please see the snippet below with the example:

```js
const saveAdamBrown = num => console.log(num);

var numberField = document.getElementById("number_field");
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('AdamBrown')[0];

numberField.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
   button.disabled = numberField.validity.patternMismatch;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number_field" pattern="[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+" />
<button class="AdamBrown" onclick="saveAdamBrown(12)">Save</button>
```